# PHP - how to echo an error in another page

Tags: php, session, echo

how would I echo an error in an IF statement on to another page,

for example i have a login form and login processing php, the IF statement is in my processing file and i want it so that if login fails to echo an error on to the login form page.

Preferably in a way that i can format the text! thankyou for any help!

Comment: There are a million and one ways to do this. The simplest would be to set a variable on your processing page which would conditionally include your login page. More complex and correct would be only accepting POST requests for your processing script, setting a ["flash" message](http://labs.iamkoa.net/2008/01/13/session-based-flash-messages-look-better-cakephp/) in the session and then redirecting to a GET request for the login page which would display the flash message.

Comment: the easiest way would be never leaving your login-page and checking the entered user data with an ajax approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can do something like this:

```
<?php
if (error) {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "There was an error";
}
?>
```

You would then redirect back to the page you would want the error to display on.

```
<?php
if (error) {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "There was an error.";
    header("Location: page.php");
}
?>
```

Then on the page with the error you would have something like this on it:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['message']; unset($_SESSION['message']); ?>
```

Remember that you would have to unset the session so that when the user refreshes the error will not be there. I hope this is what you were aiming for.

Comment: thankyou, this is pretty much what i was aiming for! very much appreciated!!

Comment: quick question, any idea how i would format the message, e.g. make the text red?

Comment: Well on the page in which you echo the session, add some html tags around it with classes. Then style it with CSS in whichever way you would like. For example: `<?php echo '<span class="error">'.$_SESSION['message'].'</span>'; unset($_SESSION['message']); ?>` You can then style it like this: .error {styles here}

Comment: ah yes! i remember now! haha thanks once again

Answer (score 3):

When you redirect to the error page, pass an error parameter:

```
if( problems ){

    header("Location: error.php?errorCode=wrongUsername");
    exit;

}
```

In your `error.php` file, write your own logic:

```
$errorCode = $_GET['errorCode'];
```

Though this is an overall vanilla approach of course.

Comment: +1 i think nothing else will be as good as your described method

Comment: Don't forget the `exit()` after your redirect `:)`

Comment: thankyou for all your feedback will try get this to work!! much appreciated!